# Laravel передать массив в шаблон

Tags: laravel

как в laravel в контроллере передать $data в шаблон? делаю так, не получается

```
    $data['title'] = "hello"
    return view('users'),$data;
```

Comment: return view('users',$data);

Answer (score 2):

```
$val['foo'] = 'bar';
$data['title'] = 'hello';
return view('users', $data);
return view('users',compact('data','val'));

return view('users')->with($data)->with($val);
return view('users')->with(compact('data','val'));

return view('users')->withTitle('hello');
```